# TikZ - Line join and line cap in a pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

is it possible to modify the `line join` and `line cap` when defining a pattern?

I tried for example the commands `\pgfsetroundjoin` `\pgfsetroundcap` but it does not work.

Here is what I get:
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\pgfdeclarepattern{
    name=herringbone,
    bottom left=\pgfqpoint{0cm}{0cm},
    top right=\pgfqpoint{2.4cm}{2.2cm},
    tile size=\pgfqpoint{2.4cm}{0.6cm},
    code={
        \pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}
        \pgfsetroundjoin
        \pgfsetroundcap
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.2cm}{2.2cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2.4cm}{0cm}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,0){
        \tikz \fill[pattern=herringbone, pattern color=black] 
            (0,0)--(-10,0)--(-10,-10)--(0,-10)--cycle;%
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The interesting part is that your code is perfectly right when used as a simple `pgfpicture` (cap and join are round) but doesn't work when used as a pattern...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem.

The pattern is "cut" at the `bottom left` and `top right` points, thus also cutting the `line join` and `line cap`.

The solution is to extend the rectangle formed by the `bottom left` and `top right` points (without changing the `tile size`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\pgfdeclarepattern{
    name=herringbone,
    bottom left=\pgfqpoint{-0.1cm}{-0.1cm},
    top right=\pgfqpoint{2.5cm}{2.3cm},
    tile size=\pgfqpoint{2.4cm}{0.6cm},
    code={
        \pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}
        \pgfsetroundjoin
        \pgfsetroundcap
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.2cm}{2.2cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2.4cm}{0cm}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,0){
        \tikz \fill[pattern=herringbone, pattern color=black] 
            (0,0)--(-10,0)--(-10,-10)--(0,-10)--cycle;%
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another point of view. Instead of drawing in two lines (up then down), make a pattern done in three lines, with only the join round (not the cap, that makes a strange behaviour, even in the solution you provided yourself).

[image: custom pattern]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\pgfdeclarepattern{
    name=herringbone,
    bottom left=\pgfqpoint{0.6cm}{-0.1cm},
    top right=\pgfqpoint{3cm}{2.3cm},
    tile size=\pgfqpoint{2.4cm}{0.8cm},
    code={
        \pgfsetlinewidth{3pt}
        \pgfsetroundjoin
        \pgfsetbuttcap
%        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.6cm}{1.1cm}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.48cm}{0.88cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.2cm}{2.2cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2.4cm}{0cm}}
%        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{3cm}{1.1cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{3.12cm}{1.32cm}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[pattern=herringbone, pattern color=black] 
                (0,0)--(-10,0)--(-10,-10)--(0,-10)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can see that I drew a bit *out of the box*, but proportionnaly, to avoid wrong vertical cut of the lines, like this:

[image: pattern creation]